# Получение координат окна

Tags: python

Каким образом можно получить координаты левого верхнего угла окна чужого приложения, используя Python?

Comment: А в Python'е есть окна? Уж ты! А если серьёзно, то немного подробней желательно, что за окно-то? Т.е. какая система, какой гуёвый пакет...

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/)

```
import pywinauto
pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re=u'calc', class_name='SciCalc')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
rect = window.Rectangle()
print rect.top()
print rect.left()
```

Для этой библиотеки есть графическая утилита, позволяющая просмативать свойства окон и генерировать python код. - [SWAPY](http://code.google.com/p/swapy/)

И я немного автор этой утилиты.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать